# Find a string between two substrings, BUT the end of the first is the start of the next one

Tags: python, python-re

So I have a string that goes like this:

```
...<p><noop><fademusic:23,0><26:1><wait:30> <speed:10><30:2><5D:1><color:3>August 3, 9:47 AM<b>District  Court<b>Defendant Lobby No. 2<color:0><p><hidetextbox:1><5D:0> <speed:255><music:8,0><wait:30><26:0><bgcolor:513,1,31><wait:7> <person:0,0,0><bg:2><bgcolor:258,1,31><wait:15><wait:30><hidetextbox:0> <name:512><shake:30,0><color:2>(Boy am I nervous!)<color:0><p> <hidetextbox:1><wait:45><name:1792><hidetextbox:0><bgcolor:769,8,31> Wright!<p>...
```

**What do I need**: find everything between <p>s. (*Note that the ending one is also a starting one for the next.*)

**My code**:

```
...
filetext = open(fn).read()
tag = '<p>'
result = re.findall(tag+"(.*?)"+tag,filetext,re.DOTALL)
print(result)
...
```

**Expected output**:

```
['<noop><fademusic:23,0><26:1><wait:30>\n<speed:10><30:2><5D:1><color:3>August 3, 9:47 AM<b>District \nCourt<b>Defendant Lobby No. 2<color:0>', '<hidetextbox:1><5D:0>\n<speed:255><music:8,0><wait:30><26:0><bgcolor:513,1,31><wait:7>\n<person:0,0,0><bg:2><bgcolor:258,1,31><wait:15><wait:30><hidetextbox:0>\n<name:512><shake:30,0><color:2>(Boy am I nervous!)<color:0>', '\n<hidetextbox:1><wait:45><name:1792><hidetextbox:0><bgcolor:769,8,31>\nWright!']
```

**Resulting output**:

```
['<noop><fademusic:23,0><26:1><wait:30>\n<speed:10><30:2><5D:1><color:3>August 3, 9:47 AM<b>District \nCourt<b>Defendant Lobby No. 2<color:0>', '\n<hidetextbox:1><wait:45><name:1792><hidetextbox:0><bgcolor:769,8,31>\nWright!']
```

Comment: why don't you use `filetext.split("<p>")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `re` module, just use `str.split('<p>')`.  You may not want the empty strings in the result if `<p>` starts or ends a string so here is a solution if so:

```py
s = '<p><noop><fademusic:23,0><26:1><wait:30> <speed:10><30:2><5D:1><color:3>August 3, 9:47 AM<b>District  Court<b>Defendant Lobby No. 2<color:0><p><hidetextbox:1><5D:0> <speed:255><music:8,0><wait:30><26:0><bgcolor:513,1,31><wait:7> <person:0,0,0><bg:2><bgcolor:258,1,31><wait:15><wait:30><hidetextbox:0> <name:512><shake:30,0><color:2>(Boy am I nervous!)<color:0><p> <hidetextbox:1><wait:45><name:1792><hidetextbox:0><bgcolor:769,8,31> Wright!<p>'
result = s.split('<p>')
for n in (0, -1):
    if result and not result[n]:
        del result[n]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['<noop><fademusic:23,0><26:1><wait:30> <speed:10><30:2><5D:1><color:3>August 3, 9:47 AM<b>District  Court<b>Defendant Lobby No. 2<color:0>', '<hidetextbox:1><5D:0> <speed:255><music:8,0><wait:30><26:0><bgcolor:513,1,31><wait:7> <person:0,0,0><bg:2><bgcolor:258,1,31><wait:15><wait:30><hidetextbox:0> <name:512><shake:30,0><color:2>(Boy am I nervous!)<color:0>', ' <hidetextbox:1><wait:45><name:1792><hidetextbox:0><bgcolor:769,8,31> Wright!']
```

If you don't want *any* empty strings, e.g., `'abc<p><p>def'` would return `['abc', '', 'def']`, then use:

```
result = [n for n in s.split('<p>') if n]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made little changes to your code. I use a lookahead assertion `(?=` to match either the next `<p>` tag or the end of the string `$`. This ensures that the regex captures text until the next `<p>` tag if it exists or until the end of the string. Here is the updated code:

```py
import re

filetext = open(fn).read()

tag = '<p>'
result = re.findall(tag + "(.*?)(?=" + tag + "|$)", filetext, re.DOTALL)

print(result)
```